# Colocar dos campos en una misma fila formulario con Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Muy buenas noches colaboradores.
tengo un proyecto en el cual voy a crear mis formularios de hecho ya los hice tengo el formulario, pero me los crea uno debajo de otro los campos, y quisiera colocar dos en la misa fila pero no consigo.
les muestro lo que he hecho hasta el momento.

he copiado de la página de bootstrap el siguiente código que como lo muestran funciona.

```css
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
    </form>
```

que es justamente el código que hay en la documentación, pero el resultado es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero yo quisiera que se muestre de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora para darles mas detalle les mostrare que tengo en el Layout de mi proyecto

```css
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Alfa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Alfa.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
 * Bootstrap v5.1.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2021 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2021 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
 */
```

He intentado actualizar mi bootstrap pero creo que tengo la última versión

También en la parte inferior de mi vista tengo este código

```js
@section Scripts {
    @{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
}
```

Les agradeceré la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Muchas gracias

Roberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías verificar desde herramientas de desarrollador, fuentes (orígenes) de tu navegador que se están cargando esas hojas de estilos,especialmente bootstrap? Esto lo haces con F12 estando el página a depurar.

Por lo demás, si encuentras error en la carga de esos estilos, puedes probar a cambiar directamente en tu página de layout y agregar el estilo desde CDN, desde luego lo mejor es verificar la ruta que tienes a partir de /libs/..., lo usual es que estos enlaces parten de una carpeta wwwroot en tu proyecto, y por tanto debería existir el archivo css en la ruta [wwwroot]/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Agrega el siguiente stylesheet para probar dentro de tu layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

**Por último y no menos importante para tu objetivo:**

Una vez cargado el stylesheet adecuadamente, todavía debes modificar tu html como te muestro, para obtener la visualización que requieres:

```
    <form>
    <div class="form-row row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Por otro lado, y para que estés más claro del ejemplo revisa este ejemplo:[Fiddle Form Bootstrap 2 Cols](https://jsfiddle.net/h9mybc1s/)

en el que si cambias el viewport, el tamaño de la ventana donde se renderiza verás que en algún momento cuando es muy pequeño, se muestra sin columnas. Si tu página es poco ancha, entonces debes cambiar el col-md-6 por algo más de acuerdo al viewport.

Comment: Estimado, vi tu respuesta hoy muy temprano, pero quería probar con la pc antes de comentar, y pues copie tu codigo y funciono al toque, ahora me pregunto porque no funciono con el ejemplo que baje de la pagina oficial de bootstrap.
Por otro lado presionando la tecla F12 Me percate de un error el cual es este, me ayudas por favor a saber de que tipo de error se trata.
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:58618/Alfa/' failed: 
(anonymous) @ aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:234

Comment: Estimado, esa pregunta corresponde a otro tema.
Sin embargo, puedes revisar documentación relacionada a IISEXPRESS con SSL, creo que el puerto que usas no es aceptable para SSL desde algunos navegadores, especialmente Chrome. En teoría se puede usar cualquier puerto pero lo recomendable es el rango de 44300 a 44399  usando un certificado auto firmado.
Véase: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20test,is%20launched%20under%20IIS%20Express.

Por favor tu puntuación a la respuesta.